# How to keep terminal window zoom factor in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04

I recently found how to set the zoom factor in the Terminal, but I have to do that again every time I start a new terminal. How to set this setting to default?

I am on ubuntu 20.04 with gnome-terminal.

Comment: see: [gnome-terminal default zoom level](https://superuser.com/questions/1584343/gnome-terminal-default-zoom-level)

Answer (score 2):

It is not easy to make a different zoom level default. The easiest option to start with larger fonts is to open the Preferences within Gnome-terminal, then on the "text" tab of the default profile ("Unnamed" by default), select a custom font with the desired size.

Apart from the shortcut keys, the only alternative option to have a different zoom level is to pass the option on the command line needed to start the terminal, e.g.

```
gnome-terminal --zoom=1.4
```

One way to make this option persistent is to create a small wrapper script `gnome-terminal` in a directory that comes earlier in the search PATH, e.g. in your `~/.local/bin` folder. If you do not have that directory, create it, and create a script `gnome-terminal` there with the content:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/gnome-terminal --zoom=1.4 "$@"
```

Make the script executable.

Log out then back in. That will cause `~/.local/bin` to be prepended to your $PATH. The command `gnome-terminal` now will point to your wrapper script, which will in turn call the "true" executable, passing the `--zoom` option and any other options.

Another option, but this will work only when launching the terminal from the applications overview, is to copy the `.desktop` launcher to your `~/.local/share/applications` directory, and edit the `Exec=` line to include the `--zoom` option. Also an alias can be defined, but that will only work to automatically pass the option from an interactive terminal.